# How do I load a local HTML file in a Safari App Extension

Tags: swift, swift3, safari-extension

I'm writing a Safari App Extension. In my extension folder I have an HTML file that I would like to read in and append to a web page using Javascript. I can't figure out how to read in the file. I'm open to doing it using Javascript or in the Swift code. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finally figuring out how to do this in the Swift code. I've only been working with Swift a couple days, so this sample may not be great but hopefully it helps:

```
// The file path below is relative to the root of the extension directory.
let filename: NSString = "folder/file.html" as NSString
let pathExtention = filename.pathExtension
let pathPrefix = filename.deletingPathExtension

if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: pathPrefix, ofType: pathExtention) {
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: .utf8) 
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in a new tab. Everything I did was in an already open tab...

Answer (score 4):

You can read a text or HTML file with a bit of XMLHttpRequest, like so:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener('load', function () {
  // file contents will be in `this.responseText`;
  console.log(this.responseText);
});
oReq.open('GET', 'myfile.html');
oReq.send();
```

Note that the URL in this example is relative. If you use this code on the global page, it will be relative to the global page. If you use it in an injected script, it will be relative to the web page that you inject the script into, which is not what you want. In this case, you'll need to use an absolute URL that begins with the extension's base URL. To get the base URL, use `safari.extension.baseURI`. Here's the 6th line from the above example but using such an absolute URL:

```
oReq.open('GET', safari.extension.baseURI + 'myfile.html');
```

A more hacky alternative to using XMLHttpRequest is to load your HTML file in an iframe inside the extension's global page, and then "reading" `document.body.innerHTML` of the iframed page from a script on the global page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to figure it out using Swift just before I saw this post so I didn't get a chance to test. Does the safari.extension.baseURI work with the new way of doing Safari App Extensions?